# How to access OBR in Apache ACE?

Tags: apache, repository, obr, apache-ace

When I run Apache ACE, console shows a message that OBR site is hosted at 
`http://localhost:8080/obr`. But when I tried to access this link nothing happens. What modification are required to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect to happen (assuming you've opened the link in a browser)? What you're probably looking for is the list of bundles installed in the OBR, which can be obtained by going to: "http://localhost:8080/obr/repository.xml"

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I was expecting that OBR site is used for viewing the stored bundles. Is it just used for viewing this repository.xml or we can use it for performing some other actions?

Comment: Well, since the repository.xml contains all bundles in the repository, it kind of lists all stored bundles. In fact, even if you copy bundles into the "store" folder manually, subsequently fetching the repository.xml will make them show up (in other words, repository.xml is regenerated whenever something in the folder changes).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Earlier, I was accessing the repository.xml in Chrome browser. It was just showing the plain xml content. That's why I had that doubt. Later, I tried accessing it in Internet Explorer - the bundles details were showing in proper format.